# Change input box background color if there is text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I saw this cool design in kahoot! where if the text is typed in the input box, it background color changes. I was wondering, is it possible to do this in jquery, javascript or css?

before
[image]

after
[image]

Comment: so you need to change color the moment you type something in ? or when you click outside of it or remove focus from it ?

Comment: please show your attempts .

Comment: @me.nkr change color the moment i type something in, and make it stays the color that it changed into, unless the text is removed.

Comment: @Swati i tried adding the `:focus` selector but it only changes color when i clicked on the box and when i clicked the other boxes, it changed back to how it were before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could try this

```js
$('#myInput').on('keyup', function() {
  input = this.value;
  if (input.length > 0) {
    $('#myInput').css('background-color', '#ccedd1');
  } else {
    $('#myInput').css('background-color', '#ebd4ca');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='myInput' placeholder='Enter Your Text Here' />
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work only for text not numeric, If you want, either remove `if(!$.isNumeric(input))`

```js
$('#textField').on('keyup', function() {
  input = this.value;
  if (input.length > 0) {
       if(!$.isNumeric(input))
    $('#textField').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='textField' placeholder='text..' />
```

Comment: why filter the numeric ?

Comment: I deleted this line `if(!$.isNumeric(input))` and it works for text and numeric. Thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value.length > 1) {
        $("element").css("background-color","blue")
             }
})
```